# Show/Hide div in a mapping ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

i'm currently learning ReactJS, and im facing an issue while tryng to hide/show a div! The following code is working, but when i'm clicking the button "Learn More" it hide every description on every card, but i would like to show/hide the description only where i clicked it.

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import JobApplicationList from './JobApplicationList';
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';



export default class Home extends React.Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            showMe:true,
            advLists: []
        }
    }

    operation(){
        this.setState({
            showMe:!this.state.showMe
        })
    }

    
    
      componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/get/adv`)
          .then(res => {
            const advLists = res.data;
            
            this.setState({ advLists });
          })
      }

      

render(){
    

    return (
        
        <div className="main-page">
            <div className="adv_container">
                {this.state.advLists.map((val, key) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="card_">
                            <Card style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>{val.compName}</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                                    {val.city} | {val.compWebsite}
                                    </Card.Subtitle>
                                    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                                    {val.salaire} €
                                    </Card.Subtitle>
                                    { this.state.showMe?
                                        <div className="description">
                                        <Card.Text>{val.description}</Card.Text>
                                        </div>
                                        :null
                                    }
                                    <Card.Link onClick={()=> this.operation()} id="toto" href="#">Learn more</Card.Link>
                                    <Card.Link href="#">Apply</Card.Link>
                                </Card.Body>
                                
                                
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

I kinda know what's going wrong, when i'm pressing the button i give the showMe state to every card, but i dont know how to fix it!
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the initial `showMe` state null and convert `operation` to take an index to toggle. If the index is already saved in state then set back to null.

```
operation(index) {
  this.setState({
    showMe: this.state.showMe === index ? null : index,
  })
}
```

Use the mapped index to pass to the handler and check this index against the `showMe` state to display the card.

```
{this.state.advLists.map((val, key) => {
  return (
    <div className="card_">
      <Card style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{val.compName}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
            {val.city} | {val.compWebsite}
          </Card.Subtitle>
          <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
            {val.salaire} €
          </Card.Subtitle>
          {this.state.showMe === key && ( // <-- check if index/key matches
            <div className="description">
              <Card.Text>{val.description}</Card.Text>
            </div>
          )}
          <Card.Link
            onClick={() => this.operation(key)} // <-- pass key/index to toggle
            id="toto" href="#"
          >
            Learn more
          </Card.Link>
          <Card.Link href="#">Apply</Card.Link>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much this is working ! I was working with the id of the card , i was so close !

Comment: @AlexisDaCosta Right, using an `id` associated with the mapped element from your data would actually be preferred, but since I didn't see any property that looked like it was unique in the data set and I didn't see anything in your code that hinted that you would be adding/removing elements from `this.state.advLists` (i.e. the array length is static) using the index is a decent fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the code pattern on how to toggle individual items using a React class component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { items: [] }; // initial state

  componentDidMount() {
    // fetched data
    this.setState({ items: [{ title: "one" }, { title: "two" }] }); 
  }

  toggleItem = (index) => {
    let items = this.state.items;
    items[index].hidden = !items[index].hidden; // mutating
    this.setState({ items }); // new object triggers re-render
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}> {/* remember to use a key */}
              <button onClick={() => this.toggleItem(index)}>toggle</button>

              {!item.hidden && item.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will probably use this for the future !